# Reload webview from another class

Tags: iphone

I want to reload a webview from another class, i've set the property and synthesized it.

When i import the webview's class in the class i want to reload from, and create the webview's class and do [class.property reload], it doesn't reload.

Update with code:

```
    CustomerDetailViewController *custDetail = [[CustomerDetailViewController alloc] init];
    [custDetail.webView reload];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your webview being created programmatically?

If so, it looks like you might be trying to reload the webview before it even exists?

If you are using a nib...

If your viewcontroller's view is the webview then:

```
 [custDetail.view reload];
```

If your webview is a subview of the viewcontroller's view then:

```
 [custDetail.view.webView reload];
```

Comment: It's created with the IB. It certainly exists before im trying to reload. There are a number of webviews in a tabbar app. When you launch the app, I display a modal view with a login screen. When the login screen is dismissed all webviews should reload.

Comment: If you have a webview in each of the tabs - then only the visible tab should reload. The other tabs should reload when you switch to them. It sounds like you are having a problem communicating between your modal view and the tabbar view controller. I'd suggest you store a pointer to the tabbar view controller in the modal view controller when you create the modal and use this property to tell the tabbar viewcontroller to reload.

Comment: I was doing that, but when you switch tabs quickly, the view keeps reloading. It should only reload once, that was my original issue.

Comment: Then I'd simply record in a variable that the data has been reloaded once and if this has been set not reload again.